# Firestore query only needed fields (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection called `books`. It's structured like this

```
{
  title: 'Book',
  text: 'Large amount of text',
  uid: 123
}
```

On some pages I need only `title` field and don't need `text` (that sometimes can be near `10mb` in size). How to fetch only those fields that I need ?

As I found from firebase docs I can only get all documents. But nothing about fields.

```
await db
    .collection('books')
    .where('uid', '==', uid)
    .get();
```

Comment: There are no client side APIs the allow the fetch of only certain fields in a document.  If you need to improve speed and minimize bandwidth by accessing only certain fields, those certain fields should be in their own document in their own collection.

Comment: Great, Thank you!